# How do I make Solr resolve cloud IP addresses in the admin UI

Tags: solr, dns, cloud, ip-address

In the Solr Admin UI, is it possible to see hostnames instead of IP addresses in the Cloud view?

I have verified that the IP addresses are in DNS and can be resolved from the Solr instance command line.

[image: Solr Admin UI: Cloud]